# Replacing image in PDF using PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I have a PDF document which has a blank image (with grey background). I need to replace this blank image with another image which I have as a byte array.

I replace the image using PDFBox as below:

```
// Convert byte array to BufferedImage
BufferedImage imgFromBytes = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes));

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                       
ImageIO.write(imgFromBytes, "jpg", baos);                       

// Replace empty image in pdf with the image generated from byte array
PDXObjectImage newImage = new PDJpeg(doc, new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
blankImg.getCOSStream().replaceWithStream(newImage.getCOSStream());
```

This replaces the blank image in the pdf. But the problem is, the image generated from the byte array is not the same size as compared to the blank image. I guess it does some auto-scaling, because of which there is some blank space at the bottom which is grey in color (due to the background of the blank image).

So I tried re-scaling the image as below:

```
// Convert byte array to BufferedImage
BufferedImage imgFromBytes = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes));

//Re-size the image
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(blankImg.getWidth(), blankImg.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g2d.drawImage(imgFromBytes, 0, 0, blankImg.getWidth(), blankImg.getHeight(), Color.WHITE, null);
g2d.dispose();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                       
ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "jpg", baos);                       

// Replace empty image in pdf with the image generated from byte array
PDXObjectImage newImage = new PDJpeg(doc, new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
blankImg.getCOSStream().replaceWithStream(newImage.getCOSStream());
```

But this doesn't help me either. I still see the grey background at the bottom. Moreover, this reduces the quality of the image and also chops a bit from the top and bottom of the image generated from the bytes.

What would be the best way to replace the blank image with the image I get from the byte array, so that it fits the size of the blank image perfectly?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to change the CTM (current transformation matrix) in the content stream of the page you're working on (use the PDFDebugger utility to see what I mean). To have better quality, use this constructor: public PDJpeg( PDDocument doc, InputStream is ) - this takes your raw jpeg stuff, i.e. don't convert to BufferedImage.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Sorry I'm kinda new to PDFBox. What is a PDFDebugger utility? Can you give me an example / point me to some documents? I converted it to a BufferedImage because I wanted to resize it.

Comment: Download the pdfbox-app here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi . See the PDFDebugger utility here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#pdfDebugger . Loading a jpeg, decompressing, resizing and recompressing means a quality loss, that is why it is better to do the resizing with the pdfbox operators that change the CTM. Your wish is a tricky one, especially if it is about several PDFs, maybe coming from several different vendors. The problem is that the display of the image and the CTM changing are different operators.

Comment: To see an example of what I mean, load the sources and run the ImageToPDF example, then load the PDF you get in the editor. Display of the image is usually done with "/Im1 Do", the CTM changing is some place before.

Comment: drunkenfist: If you also supplied a sample PDF and image, it would be easier to reproduce the exact issue and help resolving it. Especially the replacing image is drawn using exactly the same area as the original one because the target area is only controlled by the CTM @TilmanHausherr already mentioned, not the image. Thus, you cannot see background from behind the former image, that background must have a different cause.